# Can I respond to POST requests using Jetty's ResourceHandler?

Tags: jetty

Can I respond to POST requests using Jetty's `ResourceHandler`?  If so, how?

For context, here's snippet [configuring a file server](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Configuring_a_File_Server) using `ResourceHandler` from the Jetty tutorials:

```
public class FileServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

        resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ResourceHandler seems to only support GET request. This makes sense, as the ResourceHandler only serves static resources (files, directories). A POST input would be discarded anyway.

I find it hard to make up a scenario, where one would need the ResourceHandler to reply to POST requests, but if you really want to achieve this, you could write your own Handler that wraps around the ResourceHandler and calls the GET methods for POST Requests. Some hints on how to do this can be found here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/writing-custom-handlers.html#passing-request-and-response

Comment: I have a **scenario** for you... Let's say we want to test a program against `predefined responses` to POST requests. One solution could be to save the predefined responses to different files respectively. Later during tests, we use those files served by a `ResourceHandler` for easiness (laziness?).

Comment: A custom handler with POST handling can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11285610/363573

Comment: Only GET and HEAD methods are supported  by Resourcehandler as of jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.